# Integer division in Python

Tags: python, math, integer, python-2.x, integer-division

I'm confused about the following integer math in python:

`-7/3 = -3` since `(-3)*3 = -9 < -7`. I understand.

`7/-3 = -3` I don't get how this is defined. `(-3)*(-3) = 9 > 7`. In my opinion, it should be -2, because `(-3)*(-2) = 6 < 7`.

How does this work?

Comment: Python generally follows the Principle of Least Astonishment. It just always rounds down for integer division.

Comment: Here is the rationale, straight from the bdfl himself: http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/08/why-pythons-integer-division-floors.html

Comment: For people coming here for integer division help: In Python 3, integer division is done using `//`, e.g. `-7 // 3 = -3` but `-7 / 3 = -2.33..`.

Comment: Btw. mathematically there is no real difference between `-7/3` and `7/-3`, so having two different results would be a bit more complicated.

Comment: @poke You can use `//` in Python 2 as well.

Comment: To expand on what @poke said; `-7/3` == `7/-3` == `-1 * 7/3` (disregarding rounding here)

Answer (score 14):

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex):

> For (plain or long) integer division, the result is an integer. **The result is always rounded towards minus infinity**: 1/2 is 0, (-1)/2 is -1, 1/(-2) is -1, and (-1)/(-2) is 0.

The rounding towards `-inf` explains the behaviour that you're seeing.

Answer (score 4):

This is how it works:

```
int(x)/int(y) == math.floor(float(x)/float(y))
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the answers from aix and robert.

The best way to think of this is in terms of rounding down (towards minus infinity) the floating point result:

`-7/3 = floor(-2.33) = -3`

`7/-3 = floor(-2.33) = -3`

Answer (score 1):

/ is used for floating point division
// is used for integer division(returns a whole number)

And python rounds the result down

Answer (score 0):

Python rounds down.
7/3 = 2 (2+1/3)
-7/3 = -3 (-2+1/3)